# Django models queries use join

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to make query works as follow sql:

```
sql_str = '''
    select * from luckydraw_winner W
    inner join luckydraw_prizeverificationcodesmslog L on W.id =L.winner_id
    where W.lucky_draw_id = %s
    limit 10
'''
```

models:

```
class Winner(models.Model):
    lucky_draw = models.ForeignKey(LuckyDraw)
    participation = models.ForeignKey(Participation)
    prize = models.ForeignKey(Prize)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, default = None)

class PrizeVerificationCodeSMSLog(models.Model):
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Winner)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, db_index=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

because  `mobile_number` isn't always filled in `Winner` model,what I want is a winner who has  mobile number or who get the sms.So must join `PrizeVerificationCodeSMSLog` to make my purpose.
Only get winner is simple:

```
winners = models.Winner.objects.filter(lucky_draw_id=id).order_by('-created_on')[:10]
```

But I have no idea what filter can be added to join `PrizeVerificationCodeSMSLog`.

---

I have finally understood how to retrieve data I want in django.

If you want to get model `A` restricted by another model `B` which has a Foreign Key to `A`, do not try to use `filter()`. Because `A` don't know `B`,but `B` know `A`!Just retrieve `A` base `B`.

Comment: You can put name to a relationship when you add a foreign key, then A will know B through that named relationship. Check out `ForeignKey.related_name` and `ForeignKey.related_query_name` in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
logs = PrizeVerificationCodeSMSLog.objects.filter(winner__lucky_draw_id=id).order_by('-created_on')
winners = logs.select_related("winner")[:10]
```

This generates following query

```
SELECT "prizeverificationcodesmslog"."id", "prizeverificationcodesmslog"."winner_id", 
    "prizeverificationcodesmslog"."mobile_number", "prizeverificationcodesmslog"."created_on", 
    "winner"."id", "winner"."lucky_draw_id", "winner"."participation_id", 
    "winner"."prize_id", "winner"."mobile_number" 
FROM "prizeverificationcodesmslog" 
INNER JOIN "winner" ON ("prizeverificationcodesmslog"."winner_id" = "winner"."id") 
WHERE "winner"."lucky_draw_id" = 1  
ORDER BY "prizeverificationcodesmslog"."created_on" 
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I am not sure what are your requirements but you may want to agregate by Max PrizeVerificationCodeSMSLog

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: logs.select_related("winner")[:10] not work,it just return 10 `PrizeVerificationCodeSMSLog`,but I can get winner use logs.winner.It's all right,thank you.